# Nodejs Creating a function that takes a function and executes it (creating a wrapper)

Tags: javascript, node.js

my google foo is failing me with these keywords.

Essentially I'm trying to eliminate typing the same code structure over and over again around functions that I am creating, so I thought to create a wrapper around the function I want to execute. This is messy and I can't seem to figure out how to make this "work" with what I'm doing. This is what I came up with so far, and its incorrect, but I pasted it here so you can have the basic idea.

Im using promises and co-routine from bluebird.

Wrapper:

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const {coroutine: co} = require('bluebird'); //Alias coroutine

module.exports = function(func) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     co(function* () {
            try {
                //Want to execute the function here
                return func();
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        })()
    });
}
```

Function to feed in:

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const wrapper = require('./lib.js');
let arg1 = 'arg1';

wrapper(function(){
    //Print the argument then resolve
    console.log(arg1);
    resolve(arg1);
}).then((data)=>{
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
})
```

Am I on the wrong track? I keep erroring out at the resolve or at the argument. 
Essentially I just dont want to have to constantly declare the promise, co, and try/catch for each function I write.

Comment: seems like `resolve` is undefined? Did you intend to use `Promise.resolve`

Comment: My idea was to call the resolve in the original function thinking that the wrapper would know what to do with it...

Comment: Is func wrapper? You can pass resolve to fund

Comment: Tried it with Promise.resolve(), the then is not being called. I assume I need to call the resolve in the wrapper? But I need to call the resolve in the function I'm feeding it so I know its done...

Comment: func is the function I wrote in the "function to feed in section" wrapper being the alias of the file with the module.exports

Comment: You can define parameter at function within wrapper. Or define resolver function to pas to Promise constructor. Does wrapper return a function? Or call function passed to wrapper?

Comment: Goal is to just execute the function I'm passing to wrapper.

Comment: Though I posted an answer, I'm not sure how you are using this to simplify code. If possible, please push some code using these to github and share here. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not define a function to pass to Promise constructor?

Comment: Okay Ill post a link to a gist as an example. I'm writing a large library that has many async DB calls, just wanted to avoid writing the return promise, try/catch and co wrapper for each function that I am writing rather just Wrapper(function to execute).then() etc.

Comment: Here is a gist of how I was hoping to use the answer to this question:https://gist.github.com/laterbreh/17492779a499ef58ea950bc71233491f

Answer (score -1):

I think you are on the right track, but multiple issues here.

Wrapper:

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const {coroutine: co} = require('bluebird'); //Alias coroutine

module.exports = function(func) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     co(function* () {
            try {
                // Assumption: `func` returns a promise
                // run the function and 
                // then resolve/reject the promise
                func().then(result => {
                    resolve(result);
                }).catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        })()
    });
}
```

Function to feed in:

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const wrapper = require('./lib.js');
let arg1 = 'arg1';

wrapper(function(){
    //Print the argument then resolve
    console.log(arg1);
    // must return a promise here
    return Promise.resolve(arg1);
}).then((data)=>{
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: I added a gist of how I initially thought to use the answer as you requested in the comments section of the OP.